# PHP using an HTML template

Tags: php

I am having trouble reading in a file and using it as a template in PHP. A portion of my code is pasted below. For some reason it never finds $$USER_NAME$$ in the string so it never replaces. I also pasted the beginning part of my template below.

```
$filename = "email/templates/welcome.txt";
$file = fopen($filename, "r")   
$body = fread($file, filesize($filename));
fclose($file);
$body = str_replace("$$USER_NAME$$", "John Doe", $body);
print($body);
```

Template:

```
<p>
   <img src="emailPic" alt="Logo" />
</p>
<p>Dear $$USER_NAME$$,</p>
<p>Thank you for registering to attend $$EVENT_NAME$$. We look forward to helping you reach your networking goals at $$EVENT_SHORT_NAME$$.
</p>...
```

Any ideas about why it wouldn't find $$USER_NAME$$ in the template?

Comment: Try this `$body = str_replace('$$USER_NAME$$', "John Doe", $body);` Note the difference of double-quotes and single quotes.

Comment: I would suggest using `{{}}` for variable stuff in your templates. That way you are sure there is never confusion / a collision with PHP variables.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. The templates were actually made for some python code and I don't have control over them so I was just trying to get it to work with what's already there

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try with single quotes:

```
$body = str_replace('$$USER_NAME$$', 'John Doe', $body);
```

otherwise the `$` signs get interpreted by PHP (just try to do `echo "$$USER_NAME$$"` to understand that PHP will interpret it as `echo $$USER_NAME."$$"` or something similar).

You can as well resolve the problem by escaping the `$` if you still want to use double quotes:

```
$body = str_replace("\$\$USER_NAME\$\$", "John Doe", $body);
```

Check the [PHP manual page on Strings](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php) to know what are the differences between *single quoted* and *double quoted* strings in PHP.

Comment: I feel really stupid now. I've been struggling with this for hours and I never thought about PHP interpreting the $ sign. Thank you for letting me know!

Answer (score 2):

Your string "$$USER_NAME$$" needs to escape the dollar signs: "\$\$USER_NAME\$\$" or use single quotes

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
$body = str_replace('$$USER_NAME$$', "John Doe", $body);
```

Note the difference of double-quotes and single quotes. When PHP sees double-quotes, it would try to parse the value inside it as variables and since your replacement string is `$$USER_NAME$$` it your try to find the PHP variable.

You can rename you replacement string to something like `__USER_NAME__`. This will prevent the confusion.

Here is an article that I have written on [PHP double quotes vs single quotes](http://techtalk.virendrachandak.com/php-double-quotes-vs-single-quotes/)

Answer (score 1):

You are giving the $$USERNAME$$ in double quotes.Which makes php engine to interpret it as a variable.Give it in single quotes and you are raring to go.

Answer (score 1):

As others have pointed out single quotes are probably your problem. You should be able to rewrite your code as a one liner:

```
echo str_replace('$$USER_NAME$$', 'John Doe', file_get_contents('email/templates/welcome.txt'));
```

Comment: +1 for pointing out that the `fxxx()` stuff can be replaced by `file_get_contents()`, but currently there is a parse error :)

Answer (score 1):

Use this

```
$body = str_replace('$$USER_NAME$$', "John Doe", $body);
```

instead of

```
$body = str_replace("$$USER_NAME$$", "John Doe", $body);
```